# How to deal with pages having short content text?

Tags: website-design

I have a website which consists of a dozen  pages only to present and describe a company. Each page has a small paragraph displaying the information the visitors will need. The information is just in form of a title and a short paragraph.

My issue is that the pages will look almost empty and that is ugly whatever the fonts I use. How could I tackle this issue?

Comment: Add the company logo and, perhaps, an image of the most popular product...

Comment: Good idea, thank you very much @SolarMike

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend looking at the information architecture overall and see if any of these small chunks of information can be combined on pages that are similar. For example, if six of the small pages are about products, see if you could have one longer products page with all six chunks of information.

If the twelve pages are truly different from each other need to be separated, ask what you want the user to do next after reading each page. For example, should they contact the company for more information? If so, you could place a small contact form at the bottom of each page.

Does the company have a physical location, and is that important for the customer to know? You can add hours, contact info and a small map to the footer of each page to help them get to the location more easily.

Comment: Very smart first and second paragraphs, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding the company logo and even, or perhaps, an image of the most popular product or several products depending on space available and the size of the images necessary.

The challenge may become keeping the product images up-to-date as the range changes etc.